# How to use Python's FastFM library (factorization machines) for recommendation tasks?

Tags: python, recommender-system, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of `<user, item>` pairs where each entry records which user bought which item.
e.g.

```
<u1, i1>
<u1, i4>
<u2, i2>
<u3, i2>...
```

I created an encoded dataset with

```
no_of_features = no_of_users + no_of_items
```

and have set output variable y to 1, as each of those entries represented the user having bought that particular item.

Note: All `y` values are 1 in this case.

The encoded dataset looks like this:

```
user1 user2 user3 .... item1 item2 item3 item4 .... y

  1     0    0    ....   1     0     0     0   .... 1
  1     0    0    ....   0     0     0     1   .... 1
  0     1    0    ....   0     1     0     0   .... 1
  0     0    1    ....   0     1     0     0   .... 1
```

Now, I would like to know how to use `fastFM` to generate recommendations for cases `<x, y>` for any user `x` and any item `y`?

Clearly `regression` is out of the picture here. So should I use the `classification` or `ranking` approach of `fastFM`? Also how? e.g. If I use `classification`, do I need to generate instances with `y=0`? If I use `ranking` approach, do I arrange items by the output of ranking approach and recommend those with higher values?

Comment: Is there a better way of moving this question to datascience than duplicating it? For those reading, here it is on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618259/how-to-use-pythons-fastfm-library-factorization-machines-for-recommendation-t/36644243#36644243) ;-)